# Obtener las coordenadas (X, Y) de la ultima letra de un textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `dropdown` que quiero posicionar en el ultimo carácter del `textarea`, pero no se como lograrlo, he investigado como capturar la posición del cursor del `textarea` pero no he encontrado algo útil y no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo

Este es mi código que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
$(function(){
  $('textarea').on('keyup',function(evt){
    if(evt.which >= 96 && evt.which < 106){
      //console.log(String.fromCharCode(evt.which-48))
    }
    //console.log($('textarea').val());
    if($('div.dropdown').hasClass('open')){
      $('div.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }else{
      $('div.dropdown').addClass('open');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
textarea{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<div class="dropdown open">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Mi resultado esperado es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptado de [esta respuesta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446703/6561804) la cual cumple con lo que realmente busco y me da el resultado que yo busco realmente.

Lo que se hace es crear una copia de los `styles` del `textarea` en un `div` el cual el cursor del `div` seria un `span`

[Código original en GitHub](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position)

Mi código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(function(){
  $('textarea').on('keyup',function(evt){
    var pos = getCaretCoordinates(this,this.selectionEnd);
    $('div.dropdown').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': this.offsetTop - this.scrollTop + 15 + pos.top + 'px',
      'left': this.offsetLeft - this.scrollLeft + pos.left + 'px'
    });
    
  });
  

});
var properties = [
  'boxSizing',
  'width',
  'height',
  'overflowX',
  'overflowY',
  
  'borderTopWidth',
  'borderRightWidth',
  'borderBottomWidth',
  'borderLeftWidth',
  
  'paddingTop',
  'paddingRight',
  'paddingBottom',
  'paddingLeft',
  
  'fontStyle',
  'fontVariant',
  'fontWeight',
  'fontStretch',
  'fontSize',
  'lineHeight',
  'fontFamily',
  
  'textAlign',
  'textTransform',
  'textIndent',
  'textDecoration',
  
  'letterSpacing',
  'wordSpacing'
];

var isFirefox = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);
var mirrorDiv, computed, style;

getCaretCoordinates = function (element, position) {
  // clon del textarea en forma de div
  mirrorDiv = document.getElementById(element.nodeName + '--mirror-div');
  if (!mirrorDiv) {
    mirrorDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mirrorDiv.id = element.nodeName + '--mirror-div';//TEXTAREA--mirror-div
    document.body.appendChild(mirrorDiv);
  }
  
  style = mirrorDiv.style;
  computed = getComputedStyle(element);//obtenemos las propiedades del textarea
  
  // estilos por default
  style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap';
  style.wordWrap = 'break-word';  // only for textarea-s
  
  // position off-screen
  style.position = 'absolute';  // required to return coordinates properly
  style.top = element.offsetTop + parseInt(computed.borderTopWidth) + 'px';
  style.left = element.offsetLeft + parseInt(computed.borderLeftWidth) + 'px';
  style.visibility = 'hidden';  // no necesitamos que sea visible
  
  // transferir las propiedades al div
  properties.forEach(function (prop) {
    style[prop] = computed[prop];
  });
  
  if (isFirefox) {
    style.width = parseInt(computed.width) - 2 + 'px'  
    // Firefox adds 2 pixels to the padding - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753662
    // Firefox lies about the overflow property for textareas: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984275
    if (element.scrollHeight > parseInt(computed.height))
      style.overflowY = 'scroll';
  } else {
    style.overflow = 'hidden';  
    // for Chrome to not render a scrollbar; IE keeps overflowY = 'scroll'
  }  
  
  mirrorDiv.textContent = element.value.substring(0, position);
  if (element.nodeName === 'INPUT')
    mirrorDiv.textContent = mirrorDiv.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "\u00a0");
  
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = element.value.substring(position) || '.';  
  // obtenemos los valores del textarea y los escribimos en caso que se encuentre texto por delante dentro del span para obtener la posision exacta
  span.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  mirrorDiv.appendChild(span);
  
  var coordinates = {
    top: span.offsetTop + parseInt(computed['borderTopWidth']),
    left: span.offsetLeft + parseInt(computed['borderLeftWidth'])
  };
  
  return coordinates;
}
```

```css
textarea{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="dropdown open">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[textareaHelper](https://github.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper) es un plugin de jQuery que podría solucionar tu problema

Aqui un ejemplo de como funciona:

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup paste cut mouseup', function () {
  var $textarea = $(this),
      $dropdown = $('div.dropdown');
  
  // Obtenemos el alto del textarea
  var contentHeight = $textarea.textareaHelper('height');
  
  // Seteamos el alto del contenido, ya que vamos a agrandarlo a medida que escribimos
  $textarea.height(contentHeight);
  
  // Movemos el dropdown justo despues del textarea
  $dropdown.insertAfter($textarea);
  
  // Posicionamos el dropdown a las coords del caret
  $dropdown.css(
    $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos')
  );
});
```

```css
.textareaHelperContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.textareaHelperContainer .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px; /* apenas mayor al font-size */
  margin-left: 2px; /* una pequeña separacion */
}

textarea {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgithub.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper/master/textarea-helper.js"></script>

<div class="textareaHelperContainer">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="textareaHelperContainer">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div class="dropdown open">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: brother, considerando que tienes más de 1000 puntos, debes saber que es importante colocar un ejemplo que fácilmente puede ser extraído del enlace publicado. El motivo principal es evitar futuros enlaces rotos. Saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx, tienes toda la razón, debería haber hecho un comentario, mala mía. He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: dale! vamos creando entre todos el mejor sitio hispano de ayuda en la programación :D

Comment: Me gusta por la simplicidad de código pero si yo coloco otras etiquetas antes del `textarea` el cuadro que sigue al cursor del `textarea` no se mueve a la posición del `textarea`

Comment: @JuankGlezz, he actualizado mi respuesta para dar solución al problema que mencionas.